# How to load stored DATA in a DLL dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, load

***C# :***
Hey
i'm making an engine as an addon for a flight simulator 
my engine needs some data to do its work and those data i want to store them away from people text editors so i want just to make a DLL
in my DLL classes with some datas like strings lists ints ....
and lot of datas
now i want my enegine to load those data dynamically, that means i won't be including those DLLs before the compile cus i want my engine to load many DLLs using the Foreach.
i took a look at assembly load and system.reflection, but i can't get my code to work and load the variables and methods

note: all DLLs i want to load has same vars names and methods names but the data stored is diffrent 
hope you help me with this 
thnx in advance :D

Comment: That is definitely doable. If you post some of you're code and where its breaking down at can probably help provide more help.

Comment: this is what i tried but don't even know to do it :
` var DLLO = Assembly.Load("MyDLL");
            var MyVar = DLLO.get....i dont know what to put :(`

Comment: Are you not making it a bit too complicated? Why don't you store your data sets in a text file (perhaps as Json, which would help with reading/deserializing the data back into your program), and then put the text file in something like a ZIP archive. When your program needs to read the data, it can use the ZIP functionality built into .NET to get the extracted text file data from the ZIP archive. Also, why are you (seemingly) afraid of people with text editors? ;-)

Comment: cus the engine i'm making is a big work and hard to do and ofc really needed by people and if any body see the data in a txt file he will just use my engine with his own edited txt file and upload his product as his work and by product i mean airports as i said its a flight simulator add-on or plugin that is really needed
and DLL may stop people from using my work as thiers ;P

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick proof of concept let me know if need more to get you started. For our production use of this we had each library share a common interface for the classes we wanted to pull.

> My Library

```
namespace Library
{
  public class MyVariables
    {
        public string TestProp { get => "Result"; }
    }
}
```

> Calling Code

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Path");
 var results = assembly.GetTypes();
 Type type = assembly.GetType("Library.MyVariables");
 dynamic instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
 Console.Write(instanceOfMyType.TestProp);
```